# Serialize list of objects into tags for Handlebars.js

Tags: c#, json, serialization, handlebars.js

If I have a class that looks like this

```
public class DataClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

...and I create a `List<>` of those...

```
var myList = new List<DataClass>();
myList.Add(new DataClass() { Name = "Name1", Value = "Value1", SortOrder = 1 });
myList.Add(new DataClass() { Name = "Name2", Value = "Value2", SortOrder = 2 });
myList.Add(new DataClass() { Name = "Name3", Value = "Value3", SortOrder = 3 });
```

...how can I serialize it into a Json object that looks like this:

```
{
    "Name1": "Value1",
    "Name2": "Value2",
    "Name3": "Value3"
}
```

...so `SortOrder` is not serialized, and the properties become Name and Value?

This is so I can use it with `HandleBars.js`.

I have tried serializing with System.Web.Script.Serialization and System.Runtime.Serialization but I couldn't get them to ignore the SortOrder.

I also tried constructing the string manually and parsing it, but this produced a collection of arrays rather than properties as shown.

If I create an object in Javascript that looks like the example above, it works fine, but I can't seem to generate one from C# that will then work.

Comment: Is this code even compile ? In your class definition your SortOrder is string in the initialization of the DataClass SortOrder is int.

Comment: It's an example. The actual code is waaaay too big.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Newtonsoft json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)  framework to serialise data to json.
To achieve the required result I think you should convert your List to Dictionary (`myList.ToDictionary(k=>k.Name, v=>v.Value)`) and then [serialise the Dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var dataClass in myList)
{
    sb.AppendFormat(@"""{0}"":""{1}"",", dataClass.Name, dataClass.Value);
}

var result = string.Format(@"{{{0}}}", sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude Properties by adding DataContract and DataMember attributes to your class.

```
[DataContract]
public class DataClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
//Ignored
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

If you use Json.Net, you can use JsonIgnore

```
public class DataClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   //Ignored
   [JsonIgnore]
   public string Value { get; set; }
   [JsonIgnore]
   public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```